# Is this an identity: $\int_X f \, d\mu=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \mu(f^{-1}(t)) \, dt$?

Tags: integration, lebesgue-measure

Let $(X,\mu)$ be a measure space and $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ an integrable function. Does the following always hold?

$$\int_{X}f\,d\mu=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mu(f^{-1}(t))\,dt$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. The equality is not true, but we have the following proposition:

**Proposition**(Distribution formula) Let $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space, and let $f:X\to [0,+\infty]$ be measurable, then
$$\int_X f(x)\,d\mu(x)=\int_{[0,+\infty]}\mu(\{x\in X:f(x)\geq \lambda\})\,d\lambda.$$

Comment: Thanks! that's exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: Actually, this also holds if $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-finite. Because either $\mu(f \geq \lambda) < \infty$ for all $\lambda > 0$, which implies that $f$ vanishes outside of the $\sigma$-finite set $\bigcup_n \{x \mid f(x) \geq 1/n\}$, or $\mu(f \geq \lambda_0) = \infty$ for some $\lambda_0 > 0$, which yields $\int f \, d\mu = \infty$, as well as $\mu(f(x) \geq \lambda) = \infty$ for $0<\lambda \leq \lambda_0$, so that the integral on the right is also infinite.

Comment: This is an exercise from Tao's blog, You can see [245A, Notes 6: Outer measures, pre-measures, and product measures](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/30/245a-notes-6-outer-measures-pre-measures-and-product-measures/) for more details.

Comment: @XiangYu can i change the integrand to $\mu(\{x \in X : f(x)> \lambda \})$?

Comment: Of course. it doesn't matter whether we include $\{x\in X:f(x)=\lambda\}$.

Answer (score 3):

No. For example $X=[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure $m$ and $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=x$. Then,
$$\int_{[0,1]}fdm=\frac{1}{2}$$
but $f^{-1}(t)$ consists of a single point so $m(f^{-1}(t))=0$ and hence
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}m(f^{-1}(t))dt=0.$$
More generally, if $f$ is one-to-one and $\mu=m$ you will have $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mu(f^{-1}(t))dt=0$ no matter what $f$ is.

Comment: Thank you. I see now my foolishness. Is there any way to express the integral as an integral over $\mathbb{R}$? of the measure of some set in X$?

Answer (score 1):

Amplifying XiangYu's answer.  Write the integral of a nonnegative function as an "area under the graph"
$$
\int_X f(x) \;d\mu(x) = \int_X\left[\int_0^{f(x)} 1\;dt\right]d\mu(x)
$$
then reverse the order of the integrals using Fubini (Tonelli).